# iphone:how to put Home button in webView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, webview

In my app the whole view contains a webview which is my secondViewController.

Now in my web view i open the eBook.

Now i want to put home button in my webview.

My firstViewController is the home page.

Is there any way to go from webView to home view ie firstViewController?

Comment: How did you add secondViewController to first ? Did you push it to navigationController or presented it modally ?

Comment: Since you have presented a modal view just dismiss it by [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the home button to your HTML code and enclose it in a link to a unique URL
    `<a href="GoToHomePage"><img src="HomeButton.png" /></a>`

Then implement the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method to catch the click:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"GoToHomePage"]) {
        [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set title of the FirstviewController HomePage.
then write in the FirstviewController from where the secondviewController is called

```
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController secondView animated:YES];  
[secondView release];
```

then in the secondviewcontroller a navigation controller is generated and a home button is also generated to go FirstViewController.

Comment: What is this: **[self.navigationController secondView animated:YES];** ? and even if he added secondViewController to navigationController to go back to rootViewController you would do this [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: yah, for go back to Home page u can add [[self navigationController]popToRootViewControllerAnimated: YES];